# Python GUI - Passing variables between classes on button press

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a GUI containing:

- A `MainWindow` with a `QLineEdit`.
- A `CustomWindow` that is initiated by a button press from `MainWindow`.

In my application I want to pass a dataframe generated in the `CustomWindow` class back to `MainWindow`. I do this by re-initiating the `MainWindow` class with the dataframe as argument within `CustomWindow`.

By default, `MainWindow` is initiated with a dataframe equal to `None`. In this case, the `QLineEdit` should be disabled. When `MainWindow` is re-initialized with a dataframe the commands to enable the `QLineEdit` seem unresponsive. It remains disabled while it does not read any statement to disable it. As shown in the minimal working example below, the `QLineEdit` is indeed identified as the text passed is successful.

How do I get full control back over my `QLineEdit` or how should I pass the dataframe to `MainWindow`?

```
import sys

import pandas as pd

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, dataframe = None):
        super().__init__()
        
        ## Set global variable
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        
        ## Initialize different class
        self.custom = CustomWindow()
        
        ## Initialise the window
        self.window()
        
        ## Based on variable call different init functions
        if self.dataframe is None:
            self.init_main()
        else:
            self.init_custom()
        
        ## Connect buttons
        self.connectButtons()

        return None
    
    
    def window(self):
        ## Set window title and size
        self.setWindowTitle("Minimal Example")
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
    
        ## Create a window with a QLineEdit and a QPushButton
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Custom")
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        
        return None
    
    
    def init_main(self):
        ## On start-up when dataframe is None, disable the QLineEdit
        self.line.setEnabled(False)
        
        return None
    
        
    def init_custom(self):
        ## On start-up when dataframe is not None, enable the QLineEdit and set text
        self.line.setEnabled(True)
        self.line.setText(self.dataframe["Column_One"][0])
        print(self.line.text())
        
        return None


    def connectButtons(self):
        ## Connect custom window to button press
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.custom.show)

        return None
    


class CustomWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        

        ## Create a window with a QLineEdit and a QPushButton
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        
        self.connectButtons()
        
        return None


    def create_df(self):
        ## Create dataframe based on QLineEdit input
        value = str(self.line.text()).strip()
        
        if len(value) > 0:
            df = pd.DataFrame([value], columns = ["Column_One"])
            
            ## Call MainWindow and pass dataframe
            MainWindow(df)
            
            ## Close the custom window
            self.close()
        
        return None


    def connectButtons(self):
        ## Connect custom window to button press
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.create_df)

        return None



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()  
ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: btw, Although it may be a good exercise, all of the `return None` statements are redundant since python will do that for you anyway.

Comment: That `MainWindow(df)` is completely useless: it just creates a new instance on the fly, but no reference is kept, so it is immediately destroyed. Besides, if you want to update the current window with some data, you certainly should *not* create a new one. Create a custom signal for the custom window class which will emit the dataframe, connect it in the main window to a function that updates the line edit, and emit the signal in the `create_df` function.

Comment: @musicamante surely inheriting from `QMainWindow` means that the framework keeps a reference to each instance?

Comment: @quamrana Absolutely not. The only way to "automatically" make QObjects persistent without having further references is by making them children of a parent, which means that if the object is not created with a parent, an explicit persistent reference to it must be created, otherwise the garbage collector will immediately delete it. PyQt creates python *wrappers* to Qt objects: if their python reference is (or goes to) 0 and the object has no Qt owner (a parent for QObjects), then it "tells" Qt to destroy it. Which is exactly what happens in your case: no reference » window immediately deleted.

Comment: @musicamante Trying to figure it out with the signal but I am not able to get the dataframe as a variable in `MainWindow`. I am able to emit from `CustomWindow`. Could you share an example?

Comment: @TheDude Please edit your post with your attempts to use signals. Also remove those `return None` as they are redundant and useless as pointed out above.